# why does adding Sprites to Sprites in Pixi.js result in strange scaling

Tags: javascript, 2d, sprite, pixi.js

Hi, I am wondering why my sprites in Pixi.js are getting much bigger than I intended them to be.
If i add my sprite "bat" to my stage, it looks right but when I use a sprite called "background" and add my sprite "bat" to it then the size is messed up.

My background looks like this

```
function Background(screenWidth , screenHeight, imgPath)
{
    var bgImage = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(imgPath);
    PIXI.Sprite.call(this, bgImage);
    this.position.x = 0;
    this.position.y = 0;
    this.width = screenWidth;
    this.height = screenHeight;
}
Background.constructor = Background;
Background.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Sprite.prototype);

Background.prototype.update = function()
{
//DO NOTHING
};
```

My stage has exactly the same size as my Background so I wonder why my sprite "bat" doubles in size.
Does anybody knows what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your implementation, i can't be shure why it's getting bigger.

But...
Have you tried putting a PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer inside your stage and then adding your "background" and "bat" to it ?

if you don't mess with the scaling of the sprites, everyone of them should be rendered with the same measurements as their respective sourcefiles.